# Generate code from Use Case Diagram creates lots of empty classes

Tags: eclipse, papyrus

In a Papyrus Model, I clicked the Use Case Diagram (which is quite simple - contains about 5 use-cases), and selected "Designer -> Generate Java Code".

In response, I got hundreds of new packages, each of which contains hundreds of empty classes, with strange names such as "Aaixixnrpr", "Aclywqwwlr", etc...

What is happening?!

Answer (score 1):

Papyrus SW designer does not have a particular code generation support for "use case" elements, i.e. it will treat an Actor or a Use Case just as a UML class. This means that it will create an empty Java class, unless you add operations/opaque behaviors.
But the Java code generator should not create classes for elements that are not in the model. Can you please double check via the model explorer that elements such as "Aaixixnrpr" do not exist in the model?

Which version are you using? (I recommend to use version 1.0.5 from this [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/components/designer/) on an Eclipse oxygen). Btw, I also recommend to use the [Papyrus forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/121/) for questions like this.

Comment: Indeed, Aaixixnrpr and all the other classes appear in the model! I have no idea how they got there. I certainly did not create them!